# Which file do I run a cron job on to make Twitter News Feed update more often?

Tags: cron

I have installed the Twitter News Feed plugin which only updates once an hour. There is a button to press though that updates it immediately. I presume therefore that there is a file that I can call with a cron that will update as often as I set the cron for. The trouble is I don't know which file to call.

Can anyone help me out for what I should look for? These are the files available.

Plugin Files
twitter-news-feed/twitter-news-feed-admin.php
twitter-news-feed/simplepie/README.txt
twitter-news-feed/simplepie/simplepie.inc
twitter-news-feed/simplepie/LICENSE.txt
twitter-news-feed/twitter-news-feed-class.php
twitter-news-feed/readme.txt
twitter-news-feed/twitter-news-feed.php

If you need to know the contents of the files I can add them. You can read about the plugin here:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-news-feed/

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the docs. That plugin uses Simplepie as an aggregator. Google results: http://simplepie.org/wiki/tutorial/setting_up_a_cron_job_with_simplepie